# Copying/Pasting a word doc with images into a gmail

Tags: microsoft-word, gmail

I have created a flyer with images in Word 2016 that I would like to copy and paste into a gmail - not as an attachment.  I have tried it two ways - just copying/pasting the word doc and also converting the word doc to a web page but the images do not appear.  Why is this so difficult to do.  Can someone give me a step by step instruction on how to do this simple task, please.

Comment: Why would you want to copy a **Word file** (with images) to an email? Add it as an attachment and your problem is gone.

Comment: Not Sure, Maybe, [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/290936/how-to-send-a-word-document-as-an-email-message-directly-from-word) can help you with.

Comment: I know that is the simple way but I am dealing with a large group of people - a lot of whom are computer illiterate and I want to make sure they see the message.  I will attach it also but I want it to be part of the email as well.

Comment: There are very good usability reasons why you should be the content into your message, not into an attachment.    Most people don't open attachments.

Answer (score 2):

Try uploading the Word doc to Google drive, and then editing it there so it turns into a Docs file.

Then copy and paste from that.

(In general, copy and paste from Microsoft products to browser-based products doesn't work so well:  Microsoft has all sorts of special characters in their content which you cannot see but which can mess with what you paste.)